# How do I configure the path to match Python's site-package location?

Tags: path

I can get the site package location here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122327/how-do-i-find-the-location-of-my-python-site-packages-directory

Has anyone written a script that copies the results of that into path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might check out tpope's [apathy.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-apathy) for global site-packages.